# Reject Reason and Task Assigned

Tags: approval-process, process, approval-step, advanced

Wondering if you could help me with an issue I'm having.

I need to create a picklist value that states what department the rejected agreement will go back to (if it is infact rejected).

Once the department is chosen and reject is selected, the user designated to this agreement in the selected department will get a task assigned to them stating they need to rework the agreement.

The comments also need to be added from the approval record.  Do you have any possible solutions for this?

Thanks in advance!
Gina

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Very generally, you will want to use the approval process Automated Actions to automate the steps when the approval is rejected.

How you automate this will depend on what techniques you are comfortable with and will work with the scenario.

Start with the [Add Automated Actions to an Approval Process](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_automated_actions.htm&type=5) help page for the available action types.

You could, for instance, send an [outbound message](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_managing_outbound_messages.htm&type=5) that will ultimately determine the correct department and assign the user task.

Or it may be easier to use a [field update](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_managing_field_updates.htm&type=5) that will initiate process builder or an Apex trigger.